# Problems running OAuthSwift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am using OAuthSwift and whenever I run this function

```
func doOAuthTwitter(){
    let oauthswift = OAuth1Swift(
        consumerKey:   "...",
        consumerSecret: "...",
        requestTokenUrl: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
        authorizeUrl:    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",
        accessTokenUrl:  "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
    )
    oauthswift.authorize_url_handler = WebViewController()
    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/twitter")!, success: {
        credential, response in
        self.showAlertView("Twitter", message: "auth_token:\(credential.oauth_token)\n\noauth_toke_secret:\(credential.oauth_token_secret)")
        var parameters =  Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
        oauthswift.client.get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json", parameters: parameters,
            success: {
                data, response in
                let jsonDict: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)
                println(jsonDict)
            }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
                println(error)
        })
        }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    )
}
```

the function seems to run until after this point

```
oauthswift.authorize_url_handler = WebViewController()
```

authorizeWithCallbackURL doesn't even start and the jsonDict does not print. I've tried my access codes through the OAuthSwift demo, and it works fine with the tableView, printing out the JsonDict. I have no idea why authorizeWithCallbackURL goes completely ignored when I use it outside of the demo.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this problem? I have the same problem but only on iOS 8, on iOS 9 everything works fine.

Comment: Same here. I cannot understand how to get it to run the closure in the "success" part. I am able to get the access token but no luck beyond that